# How to check if an instance exists in xforms?

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0, xsltforms

I want to dispatch an action only if the instance 'addressDetails' exists (because the instance is loaded in a subform).

I tried to use the 'if' attribute of xf:action as following but didn't work:

```html
<xf:action ev:event="save" if="instance('addressDetails') != ''">
```

I got the error "Error evaluating XPath expression instance('addressDetails')".

Is there a way we can check if an instance exists ?

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 2.0, just write:

```
exists(instance('addressDetails'))
```

Or you could write:

```
count(instance('addressDetails')) > 0
```

Comment: Nope. Neither exists nor count worked. For exists, it gave an error that exists is not defined and for count it failed to evaluate the XPath expression.

Comment: As of now (temporary workaround), I have created another instance which is in the main form (not the subform) and whose value takes a boolean. On page load it is false. Once the subform is loaded, I just check if this instance value is 'true'.

Comment: `count()` should work even with XPath 1.0. Maybe a bug to report to XSLTForms (if I am right that you are using XSLTForms). But good to know you have a workaround.